# Авторизация в vk в bash-скрипте

Tags: vkontakte-api, bash

Цель: запуск браузера и автоматическая авторизация в контакт при запуске скрипта.

Проблема: цель не достигнута (авторизация не происходит)

```
#!/bin/bash
login='my_email@mail.ru';
pass='my_password';

firefox --private "https://login.vk.com/?act=login&email=$login&pass=$pass" &

echo "all done!"
```

Что сделано неправильно?

Comment: в принципе, скрипт написан правильно. а то, что авторизация не происходит, связано, вероятно, с недостаточным количеством существенных для сервера (и, вероятно, генерируемых «на лету») параметров.

Comment: я думаю, вам лучше задать **другой** вопрос по поводу того, как залогиниться на сайте vk.com с помощью url-а: что в нём должно быть перечислено. без упоминаний про bash, которые могут только «отпугнуть» специалистов по vk.com.

Comment: Попробую, cпасибо, еще отпишусь если найду ответ

Comment: Изменила ссылку на "http://vk.com/login.php?act=login&email=$mail&pass=$pass" - на лицо маленький прогресс(ввелся логин, c паролем пока что туго)

Comment: Рассмотри внимательно форму логина, там куча скрытых полей, которые тоже нужно запостить, в том числе вроде хеши айпишника и еще чего-то, что-то про капчу. Ну и может, метод гет не сработает и нужен пост. Может curl-ом проще будет.

Answer (score 1):

в принципе, скрипт написан правильно. а то, что авторизация не происходит, связано, вероятно, с недостаточным количеством существенных для сервера (и, вероятно, генерируемых «на лету») параметров.

обратите внимание на форму логина — там используется множество скрытых полей, которые тоже необходимо передать. а значения в них, судя по всему, подставляются *javascript-ом* динамически.

Answer (score 0):

- Там `POST`, а у Вас `GET`.
- Отправляются ещё несколько скрытых значений, но они вроде как статичны для одного браузера/IP (при смене одного из пары, токены меняются).